# MySQL Administrator Error ... MySQL Error Number 1103

Tags: mysql

I'm having MySQL server installed in my PC, it was running perfectly ... now i'm having an error coming when i'm trying to access to the MySQL Administrator.

the Error says

> could not connect to the specified instance.
>
> MYySQL Error Number 1103 Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to
>   this MySQL server

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read and apply the section about [Securing the initial Mysql Account](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html)?